# Asm block inside C program gives error C2400 in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I'm writing a C program that containes some anti-disassembly techniques, in particular I'm implementing this one:

https://unprotect.it/technique/dynamically-computed-target-address/

This is my attempt at implementing it:

```
__asm { 
        mov eax, [%0]
        call eax
        :: r (target) : eax
    }
```

The problem is that when I try to compile it in Visual Studio 2022 I receive the errors:

```
C2400: syntax error of the inline assembler in 'second operand'. Found 'MOD'.
C2400: syntax error of the inline assembler in 'opcode'. Found ':'.
```

Do you know how can I solve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks like a mix of the GNU inline asm and Visual C syntax. Take a look at this [comparison](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2010/fall/cs301/lecture/11_01_inline_asm.html)

Comment: MSVC doesn't support GNU C inline asm, or the weird hybrid you invented.  `__asm { mov eax, target` / `call eax` / `}` in MSVC.

Comment: BTW, that obfuscation example looks very brittle.  It depends on it being safe to re-enter `main` 4 instruction bytes later, without breaking its stack setup, access to local variables, or anything else.  Also, it assumes memory from `malloc` will be executable!  What could work is GNU C labels-as-values to get the address of a C `goto` label, like `dengo:`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html.  Take the address of that and have something jump back to that address?  Except that'll still push a return address.

Comment: MSVC 2022 64-bit doesn't support inline assembler at all.

Comment: @WeatherVane Looks like the error messages do not object to the inline assembly itself.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes that's true, so I presume it's 32-bit compiler. My 2015 one does, but not my 2022 64-bit. Microsoft [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/inline-assembler?view=msvc-170) "Inline assembly is not supported on the ARM and x64 processors. The following topics explain how to use the Visual C/C++ inline assembler with x86 processors".